# Dart: why is a list or map not equal to [] and {} respectively

Tags: list, dictionary, dart

```dart
void main() {
  var a = [];
  var b = [];
  print(a == []);
  print(a == b);
  
  var c = ['c'];
  print(c == ['c']);
  
  var d = 'd';
  print(d == 'd');
}
```

```
false
false
false
true
```

This baffles me. Why is it like this?

Edit: I just realised it doesn't have to be empty

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Dart platform libraries have chosen to, generally, not provide a native `==` implementation for mutable collections (or mutable objects in general).

Checking that `[] == []` seems obvious, but they are different objects.
If you do:

```dart
var l1 = [];
var l2 = [];
print(l1 == l2);
l1.add("an element");
print(l1 == l2);
```

do you expect the two `==`s to give the same result?
If not, how about:

```dart
var l1 = <int>[];
var l2 = <int>[];
var m = <List<int>>{l1}; // A set of lists.
print(m.contains(l2)); // true or false?
l1.add(1);
print(m.contains(l2)); // true or false?
```

On top of those concerns, which other languages also have, Dart have reified generics. An empty `List<int>` and an empty `List<num>` is not the same object, and runtime type-checks can tell the difference.
Should `<int>[] == <num>[]` then? Definitely safest to say no!

All in all, Dart does not have `==` on `List` (or other collections) recursively check whether the two lists contain the same (or equal) elements.
It only says `true` if it's the *exact same object*.

If you want to check list-element-equality, you can use the `Equality` classes from `package:collection`, like [`ListEquality`](https://pub.dev/documentation/collection/latest/collection/ListEquality-class.html) and the custom hash/equals parameters to the hash map/set classes.
Example:

```dart
const intListEquality = ListEquality<int>();
var listMap = LinkedHashMap<List<int>, String>(
    equals: intListEquality.equals, 
    hashCode: intListEquality.hash);
listMap[[1]] = "42";
print(listMap([1]); // 42
```

Comment: I would have expected `print(m.contains(l2));` to be true, honestly. I guess it's my lack of technical knowledge of data types, but I've always viewed `String`s as just a list of characters, and if `var s = '';` and `var ms = <String>{s};`, then `ms.contains('');` returns true

Comment: Strings are *immutable* "lists" (sequences) of characters (code units, really). Being immutable is important, because that means their equality is stable. Mutable lists can change, so instead of giving them an unstable equality, they got nothing, and are only equal to the same `List` object. That's stable and safe, but doesn't help you recognize when two lists contain equal elements. (Really, "contains equal elements" is just not considered the same as "equals".) Constant lists are immutable too, ... and because of canonicalization, they may be equal to the value of other constant expressions.

Answer (score 2):

It has to do with **equality checks** on Dart. They don't evaluate equality based on values, rather, they use `hashCode`s.

If you're using Dart in the context of Flutter you can use the native Flutter Method [listEquals](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/foundation/listEquals.html) for value based comparison using Lists.

If you want value based equality on other `Objects` you must `override` the `== operator` or use packages like [Equatable](https://pub.dev/packages/equatable) that helps you with that.